# What does this setting do in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: settings, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I find this setting in the preferences file:

```
// This controls what happens when pressing up or down when on the first
// or last line.
"move_to_limit_on_up_down": false,
```

Based on the short description, it seems like there should be some difference in what happens when I press the up arrow when the caret is on the first line of the file. Or when I press the down arrow when the caret is on the last line of the file.

However, when I change the value (in my user preferences file) between true and false, I can't see any difference.

There is no further description of the setting in the [unofficial documentation](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/settings.html), and google is no help either.

Comment: If the setting is enabled and the text cursor is in the middle of the first line and you press the up-key, the cursor will be placed at the beginning of the line, analog behavior in last line. If the setting is disabled it doesn't.

Comment: So @KlausPrinoth, that's an answer and it's correct. Make it an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the setting is enabled and the text cursor is in the middle of the first line and you press the up-key, the cursor will be placed at the beginning of the line. Similarly if the cursor is in the middle of the last line and the down-key is pressed, the cursor is positioned at the end of the line.
If the setting is disabled the cursor is not repositioned.